# bootstrap columns remain stacked

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

It's probably something simple, but I can't figure out why these columns are not aligning next to each other. Instead they are remaining stacked.

http://ashleykirk.ca/stylesheet/

Any tips?

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS in your question.  Most won't click out to an untrusted external link.

Comment: Unless I posted the entire CSS showing the bootstrap version number, I don't think it would have been clear what the problem is. Should I have posted the entire CSS? (still learning here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the latest version of bootstrap (you're on 2.3.2). Loading in an external file of 3.3.5 makes it work fine.

Get the latest version of bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

You're using HTML doctype unsupported by Bootstrap.
Use HTML5 doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```